Proving a sequence of functions isn't uniformly convergent
Let $f_n(x) = x^n(1-x^n)$. I need to prove that the sequence is not uniformly convergent in $[0,1]$. I have already proven that there is a pointwise convergence to $f(x)=0$. However, according to my textbook, they chose the sequence $\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{2}}$ to prove that. I chose the sequence $(1-\frac{1}{n})$. Is my proof correct?
$\operatorname{sup} \{|f_n(x)-f(x)|\} = \operatorname{sup}\{|f_n(x)\} \ge \left|(1-\frac{1}{n})^n(1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^n)\right| = (1-\frac{1}{n})^n-(1-\frac{1}{n})^{2n} \rightarrow \frac{1}{e} - \frac{1}{e^2} > 0$.
Therefore $\operatorname{sup} \{|f_n(x)-f(x)|\} \not\rightarrow 0$, which means there is no uniform convergence.

It is also fine.
